# The multi-part identifer "" can not be bound sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, identifier

```
     With Vehicles As ( 
    Select Row_Number() Over (Order By Model.[Year] Desc, Vehicle.Msrp Asc, Vehicle.Id) As RowNumber 
        , Make.[Name] As Style_Model_Make_Name 
        , Model.[Name] As Style_Model_Name 
        , Model.[Year] As Style_Model_Year 
        , Style.Trim As Style_Trim
        , Style.[Name] As Style_Name 
        , Style.BodyType As Style_BodyType
        , Vehicle.CompanyId As Company_Id
        , Vehicle.Id
        , Vehicle.StyleId As Style_Id
        , Vehicle.[Status]
        , Vehicle.Vin
        , Vehicle.StockNumber
        , Vehicle.ModelCode
        , Vehicle.Mileage
        , Vehicle.InteriorColor
        , Vehicle.InteriorColorCode
        , Vehicle.ExteriorColor
        , Vehicle.ExteriorColorCode
        , Vehicle.Certification
        , Vehicle.Selling 
        , Vehicle.Internet
        , Vehicle.Special
        , Vehicle.Comment
        , Vehicle.IsNew
        , Vehicle.IsCertified
        , Vehicle.StockDate
From dbo.Vehicle (NoLock)
    Join dbo.Style (NoLock) On Style.Id = Vehicle.StyleId
    Left Join dbo.Engine ON dbo.Style.Id = dbo.Engine.StyleId 
    Inner Join dbo.Model on dbo.Model.Id = dbo.Style.ModelId
    Inner Join dbo.Make ON dbo.Model.MakeId = dbo.Make.Id ON dbo.Style.ModelId = dbo.Model.Id
Where Vehicle.CompanyId in (9) 
    And Vehicle._IsActive = 1 
    And DateDiff(day, Vehicle.StockDate, GetDate()) >= @DaysInStock 
    And Vehicle.Msrp Between @PriceMin And @PriceMax 
    And Vehicle.Mileage Between @MileageMin And @MileageMax  And Convert(int, Model.[Year]) Between @YearMin And @YearMax And Vehicle.IsNew = 1 )

Select Style_Model_Make_Name 
        , Style_Model_Name 
        , Style_Model_Year
        , Style_Id 
        , Style_Trim 
        , Style_Name 
        , Style_BodyType
        , Company_Id
        , Vehicle.Id
        , Vehicle.Vin
        , Vehicle.Mileage
        , Vehicle.StockNumber
        , Vehicle.ModelCode
        , Vehicle.InteriorColor
        , Vehicle.InteriorColorCode
        , Vehicle.ExteriorColor
        , Vehicle.ExteriorColorCode
        , Vehicle.Certification
        , Case When Vehicle.Msrp < @CallPrice Then 0 Else Vehicle.Msrp End As Msrp 
        , Case When Vehicle.Selling < @CallPrice Then 0 Else Vehicle.Selling End As Selling
        , Vehicle.Internet
        , Vehicle.Special
        , Vehicle.Comment
        , Vehicle.IsNew
        , Vehicle.IsCertified
        , Vehicle.StockDate 
    From Vehicles  
    Where RowNumber Between @StartRowIndex And (@StartRowIndex + @MaximumRows) - 1
```

I am new to sql server and trying to figure things out. 
I am trying to create a CTE to make selecting different columns easier. I assume there is something wrong with my FROM statement but I'm not sure what exactly is wrong. All the columns in the second SELECT statement have red sqiggles which return and error of "The multi-part identifer "" can not be bound" error. Have any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Vehicle.` from column names in your main SELECT:

```
Select Style_Model_Make_Name 
            , Style_Model_Name 
            , Style_Model_Year
            , Style_Id 
            , Style_Trim 
            , Style_Name 
            , Style_BodyType
            , Company_Id
            , Vehicle.Id
            , Vehicle.Vin
            , Vehicle.Mileage
            , Vehicle.StockNumber
            , Vehicle.ModelCode
            , Vehicle.InteriorColor
            , Vehicle.InteriorColorCode
            , Vehicle.ExteriorColor
            , Vehicle.ExteriorColorCode
            , Vehicle.Certification
            , Case When Vehicle.Msrp < @CallPrice Then 0 Else Vehicle.Msrp End As Msrp 
            , Case When Vehicle.Selling < @CallPrice Then 0 Else Vehicle.Selling End As Selling
            , Vehicle.Internet
            , Vehicle.Special
            , Vehicle.Comment
            , Vehicle.IsNew
            , Vehicle.IsCertified
            , Vehicle.StockDate 
        From Vehicles  
        Where RowNumber Between @StartRowIndex And (@StartRowIndex + @MaximumRows) - 1
```